# Can I withdraw excess SOL from an associated token account?

Tags: associated-token-account

Hey I have created an associated token account, from my public key but accidentally sent some Sol to it. Is there a way to withdraw the sol from it? Will closing the account withdraw the sol from it? Thanks!

https://solscan.io/account/AgpnYB1434CF8o4scYAdgYscrScU57eRTGQ7wNNVcHUG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when closing an associated token account all SOL will be withdrawn to a destination account you specify yourself.

There is no way to decrease the SOL amount without closing the account.

Comment: to clarify, this works the same for all SPL Token Account accounts, regardless of ATA or auxiliary addressing